# Buildpacks:Update of buildpacks

Tags: docker, buildpack

I'm looking into buildpacks to create container images without Dockerfiles. One benefit should be that buildpacks are managed and are updated quite fast if some vulnerabilities are found. So it should relief the developer from that task. However, how do I know when the buildpacks I use are updated? Maybe they are also now longer compatible to my code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a command like `pack build`, it will automatically attempt to download the latest/newest version of the buildpacks you are using (technically it attempts to download the newest "[builder](https://buildpacks.io/docs/concepts/components/builder/)" version). You can control/override this with the `--pull-policy` option, which can be set to `always`, `never`, or `if-not-present`.

Knowing if a new version is available may depend on the buildpacks and builder you are using. You could attempt a `docker pull` of the builder image or a `pack buildpack pull`. If it does not pull anything, then there is no update.

In addition, the [Buildpack Registry](https://registry.buildpacks.io/) contains release information for buildpacks that have been published there.

Comment: An alternative way of thinking, but unless you are specifying specific buildpacks to run, like with `pack -b`, you don't actually need care if a buildpack has been updated. All you really need to watch is the builder. The builder bundles up all of the buildpacks, and the builder's author will keep it up-to-date for you. Another nice facet of buildpacks. As @codefinger said, if you have pull policy set to always, pack will check and ensure you always have the latest builder. Otherwise, look into your CI to see if it can monitor a docker repo for updates. Most can.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answers! However doesn't it contradict the docker "best practices" to never use the :latest in production ready Dockerfiles? Because the resulting image would change without "directly knowing". When moving from Dockerfiles to buildpacks I am tempted to  use 
'--pull-policy never'
at least from a public repository.

Comment: Something else I should add is that in most CVE cases, the buildpack itself doesn't need to be updated. The buildpacks are capable of applying security patches runtimes and dependencies by rerunning them.

Comment: @Oli using `:latest` is optional. You can also explicit pin to a version of a builder/buildpack image. But then you would need to check for an update of that image yourself